# Detect popup window for incoming call for mute the app music

Tags: android, popupwindow, incoming-call

What is the best practice for detect small popup window for incoming call?
I need it for mute music in my game.
I really do not want to use "dangerous permission" `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

The method in activity `onPause` is not called.